# Is this a proper superset of Carmichael numbers?

Tags: number-theory, primality-test, pseudoprimes

While looking into the [Lucas primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_primality_test) I noticed an interesting thing. Using the following test`*` I discovered a sequence of numbers which, for lack of a better name, I'll call the *"Poulet-Carmichael numbers"*:

*For all prime factors P of N-1 if the congruence $P^{(N-1)} \equiv 1 \mod N$ holds true then N is either prime or a Poulet-Carmichael number.*

The sequence of composites that pass the test includes **all** of the Carmichael numbers plus a small subset of the [super-Poulet numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super-Poulet_number). A cursory search of [OEIS](https://oeis.org/) turned up no result for either that particular sequence nor the non-Carmichael subsequence (12801, 83333, 104653, 113201, 282133, 653333, 721801, 1530787, 1584133, ...).

So my question is simply whether there is any justification whatsoever to classify this sequence as a superset of Carmichaels proper? Without any evidence as such I suppose that would be jumping the gun just a bit. Any thoughts on the matter?

`*` Incidentally this turns out to be an excellent "pretest" for the Lucas primality test as it tends to filter out all but the most resilient pseudoprimes.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question.  It's obvious that any Carmichael Number satisfies your test...indeed, if a prime $p$ divides $N-1$ then it clearly does not divide $N$.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: I see what you mean, since by definition a Carmichael number satisfies that congruence for all bases coprime to N.

Comment: Exactly.  And since you have found some numbers which pass your test but which are not Carmichael Numbers we know that this class of numbers is strictly bigger than the class of Carmichael Numbers.

Comment: Right so in conjunction with the fact that, for example, there seems to be no obvious connection with the non-Carmichaels and Korselt's criterion we can safely assume that there is therefore (as of yet at least) no real justification to deem this to be some sort of superset of Carmichaels. Agreed?

Comment: I don't understand.  It is a superset of the Carmichael Numbers, in that it contains them and contains some other numbers as well.  I have no idea if it is an interesting superset or not.  Some obvious questions:  are there infinitely many non-Carmichaels in your set?  Is there a Korselt-like test that determines your class?  And so on.

Comment: I guess I was thinking in terms of some intrinsic connection which, as you've point out, isn't at all a requirement in constructing supersets (or sets for that matter). And no I couldn't find any such Korselt-like criterion myself so far...

Comment: Silent upvote for your comments, by the way. Cheers!

Comment: Good luck! $\quad $